# How to make padding look the same in moz and webkit browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, vendor-prefix

So I'm developing these elements and trying to figure out why they look different in moz and webkit browsers. Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <span class="facet-count">2</span>
  <span class="facet-count">4</span>
  <span class="facet-count">16</span>
  <span class="facet-count">256</span>
  <span class="facet-count">65536</span>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.facet-count {
  padding: 3px 7px;
  background: #0896ea none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Here is a link to the demo: http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/OMNMra

Is there any fix I can apply to make those facet-counts look the same on all browsers? And by same, I mean how they look on Firefox. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a CSS reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the height difference you can add:

```
line-height: 13px;  
display: inline-block;
```

For the text weight difference you can try:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

But typically you can't make Moz and WebKit display text 100% exactly the same. Try Google Fonts. They are more cross-browser consistent than built in system fonts like Helvetica.